# Unix File Transfer to RAM

Tags: file, unix, transfer

I am working on Unix server. I need to transfer a file from one unix server's disk space to Other unix server's RAM (in -memory). I could not find exact option to perform the task. I am not allowed to use  mount with ramfs and tmpfs also. Pls suggest me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could slurp the entire file with a couple of lines of Perl, or use PHP's `file_get_contents()`

```
$file = file_get_contents('someFile');
```

I assume here that the remote server's disks are NFS-mounted. If that is not the case, you could use a different URI.

---

Or you could use `netcat` on the receiver:

```
file=$(nc -l 5000)
```

and on the sender:

```
nc RECEIVER_IP 5000 < diskfile
```